# Assigning different names to columns in list using tidyr::pivot_longer, and combining them

Tags: r, list

I'm extracting "wide" data which I intend to tidy with `tidyr::pivot_longer()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <-
  data.frame(
    M = words[1:10],
    N = rnorm(10, 3, 3),
    O = rnorm(10, 3, 3),
    P = rnorm(10, 3, 3)
  )

df2 <-
  data.frame(
    M = words[1:10],
    N = rnorm(10, 3, 3),
    O = rnorm(10, 3, 3),
    P = rnorm(10, 3, 3)
  )

df3 <-
  data.frame(
    M = words[1:10],
    N = rnorm(10, 3, 3),
    O = rnorm(10, 3, 3),
    P = rnorm(10, 3, 3)
  )

df4 <-
  data.frame(
    M = words[1:10],
    N = rnorm(10, 3, 3),
    O = rnorm(10, 3, 3),
    P = rnorm(10, 3, 3)
  )

lst <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

colname <-
  c("ticker", "2017", "2018", "2019")
header <- list("Leverage", "Gearing", "Capex.to.sales", "FCFex")

lst <- lst %>% 
  lapply(setNames, colname) %>% 
  lapply(pivot_longer, -ticker, names_to = "Period", values_to = header)
```

Using `values_to = header` gives me this error:

> Error in [[<-.data.frame(*tmp*`, ".value", value = list("Leverage",  : 
>     replacement has 4 rows, data has 3

Instead, I had to use the default `values_to = "value"`, and subsequently use this code to rename my columns:

```r
lst <- lst %>% 
  lapply(setNames, colname) %>% 
  lapply(pivot_longer, -ticker, names_to = "Period", values_to = "value")

lst <- map(seq_along(lst), function(i){
  x <- lst[[i]]
  colnames(x)[3] <- header[[i]]
  x
})
```

My output is shown below (columns renamed), but I was wondering if there is a way to feed a vector into `values_to` instead of using `map` (as it makes for better piping)? Or is there a more efficient way about going about this?

```
> lst
[[1]]
# A tibble: 30 x 3
   ticker   Period Leverage
   <fct>    <chr>     <dbl>
 1 a        2017      6.01 
 2 a        2018      4.82 
 3 a        2019      1.58 
 4 able     2017      8.64 
 5 able     2018      6.70 
 6 able     2019      0.831
 7 about    2017     -0.187
 8 about    2018      0.549
 9 about    2019      0.829
10 absolute 2017      1.26 
# ... with 20 more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 30 x 3
   ticker   Period Gearing
   <fct>    <chr>    <dbl>
 1 a        2017    2.37  
 2 a        2018    3.58  
 3 a        2019    5.63  
 4 able     2017    0.311 
 5 able     2018    0.708 
 6 able     2019   -0.0651
 7 about    2017    2.89  
 8 about    2018    6.25  
 9 about    2019   10.1   
10 absolute 2017    6.48  
# ... with 20 more rows

[[3]]
# A tibble: 30 x 3
   ticker   Period Capex.to.sales
   <fct>    <chr>           <dbl>
 1 a        2017            5.22 
 2 a        2018            1.88 
 3 a        2019            0.746
 4 able     2017           -3.90 
 5 able     2018            3.06 
 6 able     2019            1.91 
 7 about    2017            1.35 
 8 about    2018            4.12 
 9 about    2019           11.1  
10 absolute 2017            1.76 
# ... with 20 more rows

[[4]]
# A tibble: 30 x 3
   ticker   Period  FCFex
   <fct>    <chr>   <dbl>
 1 a        2017    1.76 
 2 a        2018    2.85 
 3 a        2019    1.86 
 4 able     2017   -3.38 
 5 able     2018   -3.02 
 6 able     2019   -1.52 
 7 about    2017    6.46 
 8 about    2018    5.39 
 9 about    2019    0.810
10 absolute 2017    8.08 
# ... with 20 more rows
```

For the second part of my question, I intend to use `bind_col()` to combine all the four dataframes into one, but the two common columns are being duplicated (as seen below).

How do I tell R to just bind the rightmost column that was renamed i.e. exclude the first two columns for the last three dataframes? Thank you.

```
Metrics <- bind_cols(lst)

> Metrics
# A tibble: 30 x 12
   ticker Period Leverage ticker1 Period1 Gearing ticker2 Period2
   <fct>  <chr>     <dbl> <fct>   <chr>     <dbl> <fct>   <chr>  
 1 a      2017      6.01  a       2017     2.37   a       2017   
 2 a      2018      4.82  a       2018     3.58   a       2018   
 3 a      2019      1.58  a       2019     5.63   a       2019   
 4 able   2017      8.64  able    2017     0.311  able    2017   
 5 able   2018      6.70  able    2018     0.708  able    2018   
 6 able   2019      0.831 able    2019    -0.0651 able    2019   
 7 about  2017     -0.187 about   2017     2.89   about   2017   
 8 about  2018      0.549 about   2018     6.25   about   2018   
 9 about  2019      0.829 about   2019    10.1    about   2019   
10 absol~ 2017      1.26  absolu~ 2017     6.48   absolu~ 2017   
# ... with 20 more rows, and 4 more variables: Capex.to.sales <dbl>,
#   ticker3 <fct>, Period3 <chr>, FCFex <dbl>
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample for `words` to make this reproducible? It would really help understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Apologies, forgot to include the library needed (tidyverse). The example should be reproducible now. 

It is the values_to argument which I'm trying to rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

lst <- map(lst, setNames, colname)

map2_dfc(lst, header, ~ pivot_longer(
  .x, -ticker, names_to = "Period", values_to = .y)) %>% 
  select(c(1:3, 6, 9, 12))
```

Output:

```
   ticker   Period Leverage Gearing Capex.to.sales FCFex
   <fct>    <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a        2017      6.20     3.43          7.87   7.52
 2 a        2018      1.63     3.30          0.126  1.52
 3 a        2019      2.32     1.49         -0.286  6.95
 4 able     2017      6.38     3.42          7.34   2.60
 5 able     2018      0.763    1.68         -0.648 -2.85
 6 able     2019      5.56     2.35         -0.572  3.21
 7 about    2017     -0.762    1.49          3.12   2.43
 8 about    2018      9.07    -1.22          0.821  4.00
 9 about    2019      1.37     8.27         -0.700 -1.05
10 absolute 2017      1.39     2.49          0.390  2.40
# … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a very elegant solution indeed.

Comment: Well, using `purrr::map2_dfc()` is neat because it allows to use 2 lists (`lst` and `header`) and that solves the problem you had with using `header` directly + it directly `bind_cols()` the result. Selecting the columns manually with `select()` as I did at the end is far from elegant though. There might be a nicer way to sort the repeated columns. Maybe with `left_join()` instead of `bind_cols()`. But it is not super easy to use in this context